# Show Admob banner in a list

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob

Using `Ionic 3`, I have a list of items. every x items, I want to be able to show a banner (i % x = 0)

The Issue is that as far as I know, Admob doesn't let you show an ad in a pre-defined container but just as position in the screen.

Is there a way to do it that I'm missing? in android there is `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` as a container. Something similar in `Ionic`?

If not, Is there another ad platform that does allow something similar?

Comment: you can try mopub to host admob ads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720476/ionic2-ionic3-how-to-use-banner-in-list-of-items-scroll-able-page-using-ad

Comment: you got any solution ???